# Monotouch: WSDL and WebService parameters

Tags: web-services, xamarin.ios, wsdl, monodevelop

I'm developing an iPhone application with Monotouch and using a ASMX web-service.
The WebReference was added correctly (thanks to .wsdl file) and I started to use my WS reference:

```
public static string CallWs(string[] arrData_, 
                                        List<string[]> lstObject_)
{
    WebService webService = new Service ();
    webService.CallMethod(arrData_, lstObject_);
}
```

My web-service has a correct method `public void CallMethod(string[] arrData_, List<string[]> lstObject_)`, the .wsdl file describe it correctly (`ArrayOfArrayOfString`) but MonoTouch sees it like `public void CallMethod(string[] arrData_, string lstObject_)`.

So, I tried to modify my method to `string[][]`: **same issue**

I tried to use NewtonSoft.Json DLL to parse my data but this needs System.Drawing implicitly (that is not present with Monotouch, CoreGraphics replaces it), so it can be found and resolved.

**EDIT :**

The current solution is editing the Reference file and change the parameter type.

Is there an other solution ? why MonoDevelop does not recognize correctly my web service ?

Comment: Have you tried using SLSvcUtil.exe to generate the proxy?  See here: http://docs.xamarin.com/android/tutorials/Introduction_to_Web_Services?highlight=wcf  Also, for Newtonsoft.Json to work, you should use the portable class library version they provide, and compile from source in MonoTouch.

Comment: That's not a proxy issue, MonoDevelop fond correctly my WS. But the reference file is wrong. The solution I found is editing it manually. I don't understand why it does not recognize my method parameters correctly.

Comment: About Newtonsoft.Json, good to know, thanks a lot! (but with string[][], it's not necessary anymore..)

Comment: If you use SLSvcUtil.exe (on Windows) it could generate the proxy differently and work properly.  It is worth a try if it causes you issues later on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Collection types such as `IList<string>` are not fully supported yet.

There are two main problems here:

- Creating the client proxy from WSDL.

  You can work around this by using `SLSvcUtil.exe` on Windows.
- Message Serialization

  This is the more serious problem as it prevents you from talking to the remote service.

I already implemented some of the missing pieces last week, but it's not complete yet.  Dictionary types are still missing and I also need to do some more tests with arrays and more complex types such as arrays of arrays.

Another issue is more cosmetic: there is no difference between

```
    [OperationContract]
    IList<int> GetSimpleList();
```

and

```
    [OperationContract]
    int[] GetArray();
```

in the WSDL (both are `ArrayOfint`).  Visual Studio lets you configure the collection type (right-click your Service Reference, select "Configure Service Reference", there's "Collection Type" in the middle of that dialog) that should be used in the generated client proxy.

MonoDevelop doesn't support that yet and uses arrays (or better: it *should* use arrays; at the moment, it's simply crashing.  I'll have a look at that).